# Struggling with NSDictionary and plists

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

I'm trying to search through the plist, find if Available is true. 
here's my plist.

Image of plist: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gvjp.jpg

After searching the Cocos2D forums and here, I've managed to attempt my own effort but not getting very far with it.

Here's the code.

```
NSString  *fullPathToPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"missions" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray  *MissionsList;
NSDictionary  *plistDict;
NSInteger     pIdx, mCount;

plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: fullPathToPList];
MissionsList = [plistDict valueForKey: @"Missions"];
mCount = [MissionsList count];
NSLog(@"Number of Missions in plist = %d", mCount);

for (pIdx = 0; pIdx < mCount; pIdx++)
{
NSDictionary *eachMission = [MissionsList objectAtIndex: pIdx];
NSString *MissionName = [eachMission valueForKey: @"mission name"];
NSString *Available = [eachMission valueForKey: @"Available"];

NSLog(@"\nMission[%d] \nName = %@, \nAvailable = %@", pIdx, MissionName, Available);
}
```

What i'd like to be happening here, is for it to be returning

```
Mission 1
Name = First Mission
Available = 1
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Use `objectForKey`, not `valueForKey` to get the contents of a dictionary (unless you explicitly what to do some "Key-Value Coding" magic). - 2) The value of the "Missions" key seems to be a *dictionary*, not an *array*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your picture `Missions` is a dictionary rather than an array. So you need to read them differently.

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = ...;
NSDictionary *missions = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Missions"];
[missions enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSDictionary *mission, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *missionName = [mission objectForKey:@"mission name"];
    NSNumber *available = [mission objectForKey:@"Available"];

    NSLog(@"Mission: %@, Name = %@, Available = %@", key, missionName, available);
}];
```

Note that you won't necessarily get the missions back in the same order as they are defined in the dictionary. Therefore you also can't get the index. If you need to know the index, you need to change the `Missions` object to an array instead in the plist.

Also note that `Available` is defined as `boolean` in your plist, therefore you should store the value in an `NSNumber`.